# SQlite, не выходит удалить через строку

Tags: sqlite, android

При попытке удалить строку из базы данных через:

`db.delete("dictionaries", "dictionary = " + "eeee", null);`, — ничего не выходит!

Но когда я удаляю через:

`db.delete("dictionaries", "id = " + 4, null);`, — все выходит.

Что я делаю не так и как исправить, чтобы удаляло через строку? Вот фото базы данных:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Под "ничего не выходит" имеется в виду что не удаляется запись или приложение падает с ошибкой?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, падает с ошибкой...

Comment: Это крайне важно. Надо это добавить в вопрос. Также крайне важно и вообще необходимо представить тип ошибки и её stackTrace.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, может объясните уже, что такое stacktrace, чтобы я весь лог не кидал?)) Я в гугле не нашел (искал на русском).

Comment: Когда "выстреливает" исключение, в логах может выводиться последовательность функций, которые исключение успело пройти без поимки (обычно до самого низа, что и приводит к крашу). Это фрагмент стека вызовов, "след" (trace) исключения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно ответам к этому [вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314176/3212712) проблему можно решить двумя способами:

1. Добавить одинарные кавычки и окружить ими значение колонки.

   ```
    db.delete("dictionaries", "dictionary = " + "'eeee'", null);
   ```
2. Передать в метод не строку со значением колонки, а массив строк, содержащих значения таким образом:

   ```
    db.delete("dictionaries", "dictionary" + "=?", new String[] { "eeee" });
   ```

Comment: Заработало! Но... Почему?

Comment: Судя по всему дело тут в том, что SQL требует заключение строковых  значений в кавычки. При этом, передавая массив строк (2 вариант) строки автоматически этими кавычками окружаются.